# How can I tweak the Google Analytics tag via Google Tag Manager to enable Enhanced Link Attribution

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution after reading the docs I'd like to edit the UA tag in GTM to add this line:
`ga('require', 'linkid');`

Questions:

- Couldn't find the actual GA tag code in GTM
- Should it be `linkid` as a generic name or I should write a dedicated line for every link on the page?

Comment: Google Analytics tags don't have to be in Google Tag Manager.   Maybe you have the GA snippet directly in your page source?

Comment: I believe GTM should be the way to make it all right, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the GA Settings variable.
Under More Settings > Advanced Configuration > Enable Enhanced Link Attribution
Set to true
[image]